# JAXB annotations for enums

Tags: xml, enums, annotations, jaxb

I have the following enum definition:

```
public enum MyEnumeration{

  ENUM_ONE("1","foo"),
  ENUM_TWO("2","bar");

  private String code;
  private String description;

  public String getDescription()
  {
     return this.description;
  }

  public String getCode()
  {
     return this.code;
  }    
}
```

And I want to annotate it with Jaxb annotations so it will be marshalled into the following xml.

```
<myenumeration>
  <code>...</code>
  <description>...</description>
</myenumeration>
```

I've tried several approaches, but wasn't succesful. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write an `XmlAdapter` that converts the enum into a domain object with those properties.  For examples of using `XmlAdapter` see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your link shows me several blogposts. Which would you suggest to review? Or else how would I start doing this?

Comment: @Bjarne77 - This would be a good one to use:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html